# How to remove block comment in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is an existing block comment in repo, I want to remove that block comment.

My Mac Visual Studio Code shortcuts say (`Shift + Option + A`)  is shortcut to toggle block comment. That does not remove block comments instead block comments that block of commented lines

```
Actual Code:
 /*
 * const selectedIndex = activePoint[0]._index;
 * const selectedDatasetIndex = activePoint[0]._datasetIndex;
 */

On Toggle Block Comment:
/*/*
 * const selectedIndex = activePoint[0]._index;
 * const selectedDatasetIndex = activePoint[0]._datasetIndex;
 */*/

Expected output:
const selectedIndex = activePoint[0]._index;
const selectedDatasetIndex = activePoint[0]._datasetIndex;
```

Comment: I don't believe that is a standard vscode block comment.  They aren't in that format. 
 It was probably added by an extension and hence you would have to figure out that same extension to toggle its comments.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Visual Studio Code documentation the shortcut to uncomment selected text in mac is:

`⌘K ⌘U`

Reference https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf

Comment: ⌘K ⌘U is for line comment in the pdf above, my question was on block comment also I must look at preferences in my VSCode and not the doc.

Answer (score 0):

highlight the code block either using the cursor or right-click, and use backspace to delete the code block.